# INVALID_NONCE authenticating on Crypto.com C# REST API

Tags: rest, authentication, bad-request

I am working on private endpoints of Crypto.com, and I am receiving the following problem

```
{
   "id":60,
   "method":"private/get-currency-networks",
   "code":10007,
   "message":"INVALID_NONCE"
}
```

when sending the message

```
"{\"id\":60,
\"method\":\"private/get-currency-networks\",
\"nonce\":1667591280642,
\"params\":{},
\"sig\":\"xxxxxxx\",
\"api_key\":\"xxxxxx\"
}"
```

with signature Hex encoded and all. I tried to get nonce using UTCtime since the Epoch:

```
  long nonce = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds();
```

But I still receive the error message that according to the documentation means "Nonce value differs by more than 30 seconds from server"

Answer (score 0):

for me it helped substracting 10 sec from the current-time when setting the nonce, like:

```
.setNonce(LocalDateTime.now().minusSeconds(10).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli())
```

see:
https://exchange-docs.crypto.com/exchange/v1/rest-ws/index.html#invalid_nonce-on-all-requests